# Where is my stupid mistake using rotation matrix to convert Galactic to Equatorial coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am attempting to apply a rotation matrix in javascript to convert celestial  galactic coordinates to Equatorial coordinates.
I am  using the published Galactic coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system
 αG = 192.85, δG 27.13, lNCP 122.93

```
var alphaG =radians(192.855); 
var deltaG = radians(-27.12825);// neg since dec is up from the equator (XY plane) not down
var L = radians(122.932);
```

and have independently arrived at Wikipedia's rotation matrix for Z1Y2Z3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles:

```
T[0] = [c1*c2*c3 - s1*s3, -c3*s1 -c1*c2*s3, c1*s2];
T[1] = [s1*c2*c3 + c1*s3, -s1*c2*s3 + c1*c3, s1*s2];
T[2] = [-s2*c3, s2*s3, c2];
```

where

```
var c1 = Math.cos(alphaG);
var s1 = Math.sin(alphaG);
var c2 = Math.cos(deltaG);
var s2 = Math.sin(deltaG);
var c3 = Math.cos(L);
var s3 = Math.sin(L);
```

and subsequently supplied Galactic coordinates as

```
var l = radians(document.getElementById("GLon").value); 
var cl = Math.cos(l);
var sl = Math.sin(l);
var b = radians(document.getElementById("GLat").value);
var cb = Math.cos(b);
```

(radians is simply Math.PI()/180)

to

```
 var x =
        T[0][0]*cl
        + T[0][1]*sl
        + T[0][2]*cb
    var y = 
         T[1][0]*cl
        + T[1][1]*sl
        + T[1][2]*cb
   var z = 
         T[2][0]*cl
        + T[2][1]*sl
        + T[2][2]*cb
```

and converting the result to ra/dec with

```
 var ra2 = degrees(Math.atan2(y,x));
 var r = Math.hypot(x,y);
 var dec2 = degrees(Math.atan2(z,r));
```

But I'm getting the wrong results, for example, the Pole (0, radians(90)) returns 72.89, -14.35 not the expected 192.86 ,-27.13.

code at https://codeshare.io/5o3eWB

Answer (score 1):

Not one, but 4 mistakes:

1. Y2 should be [c2, 0, -s2] [0,1,0] [s2, 0 , c2] not  [c2, 0, s2]
   [0,1,0] [-s2, 0 , c2]
2. The order of rotations should be Z3 * Y2 *Z1 not Z1 * Y2 * Z3
3. the rotations require tweaking:
        δG is 90-27.12825  not 27.12825
        lNCP is 180 - 122.93 not  122.93

So the variables are:

```
var alphaG0 =radians(192.855);
var deltaG0 = radians(90-27.12825)
var L0 = radians(180-122.932);
```

and the rotation matrix is :

```
T[0] = [c1*c2*c3 - s1*s3, s1*c2*c3 +c1*s3, -s2*c3];
T[1] = [-c1*c2*s3 - s1*c3, -s1*c2*s3 + c1*c3, s2*s3];
T[2] = [c1*s2, s1*s2, c2];
```